# How to find a radio on a Linux Machine using Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, linux, opencv

Hello I'm doing a home project where I want to use two radios: one connected directly to an FPV camera and one connected to a Linux laptop via USB.

The thing that's getting me stumped is finding the radio on my Ubuntu 16.04 Linux machine via Python.

I know there is Mission Planner used specifically for telemetry and FPV data but I also want to analyze the video using OpenCV. I have it working with the camera connected to the laptop directly but not with any radios.

Looking around the internet I've seen people mention ttyAMA0 in the /dev directory but when I use that as an argument for the OpenCV function VideoCapture() it throws an exception and says it can't open the video. Same thing when I just put in 0 or 1. (my laptop doesn't have a webcam but just in case I tried both)

I also have a version of my code in C++ if anyone knows that way instead.

Any help would be appreciated.

Ashley

Comment: A radio? What sort of radio?

Comment: Unusual for a radio to be connected to a camera.  You will need to make sure that they are both tuned to the same station.

Comment: RFD900. It uses SiK radio firmware

Comment: @ThomasMatthews When you say station do you mean Baud rate? I have the transceiver and receiver both set to 57600 but I can adjust it to a different one if needed.

Comment: What is an FPV camera? Which model? Please try to be a bit more complete in your description so folks can assist you.

Comment: I have a two cameras that I'm trying out. One is a RunCam Eagle 2 FPV camera. The other isn't really considered FPV, a Pixy IR-Lock camera, but it would be cool to get it working with it for future projects.

Comment: I am still unclear what the real question or issue is, or how everything is connected. `ttyAMA0` seems most unlikely as the source for anything high bandwidth (e.g. video, radio) because that is normally a serial device. Have you tried disconnecting all your devices, rebooting and running `ls -lrt /dev > /tmp/a` then connecting your devices, waiting 3 seconds, and running `ls -lrt /dev > /tmp/b` and then `diff /tmp/[ab]` to see what new devices you get on attaching hardware.

Comment: So my program is run taking in a path to a camera as an argument to be used with OpenCV's VideoCapture function like cam = VideoCapture(arg). My issue is finding the correct path to pass in as an argument. Connection-wise: The camera is connected to the radio transceiver, the radio receiver is connected to the laptop. I want to get the live video from the camera over to the laptop using the RFD900 radios to then be used in a Python program to be analyzed.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'll try that and see if anything is different

Comment: My golly, what a rubbish data sheet and manual. No indication of what the heck it actually does, but just piles straight in with gain and range graphs on page 1 and that it has a passive front-end band-pass filter, some RP-SMAs and an RX SAW!

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand. Are you using the radio to transmit the images? Do you realise it'll be slow? What size images are they? Colour? Or greyscale? Why are you talking about 2 cameras? Which one is causing the problem? Is the other one relevant?

Comment: Have you tried reading the serial port? `sudo screen /dev/ttyAMA0 57600`

Comment: Are your devices communicating through wireless?  A common radio (like ones in cars) can receive transmissions on various wavelengths.